# getProcAddressW errors when use visual studio2005 and windows mobile SDK to debug windows CE project

Tags: c++, windows-ce, getprocaddress

I am using `Visual Studio 2005` and `Windows Mobile 6 Professional Device SDK` to debug a `Windows CE` project (copied from a Windows project ). I use active sync to connect PC and Win CE device. Then I create a new Windows CE project (copied from Windows project, but create using windows mobile 6 professional device SDK as platform. vc++, smart device, console app ).

When I build the windows CE project, there are some errors:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'GetProcAddressW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [21]' to 'LPCWSTR' xxxxx.cpp   42
```

It occurred after I used `LoadLibrary(_T(xx.dll));` then I used `GetProcAddress(handle,"functionName");`

If I change it to use `GetProcAddress(handle, _T("functionName") );` this error dispears. But
new error

```
LINK: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_Function2 
    referenced in function wmain    xxxx.obj
```

occured, Function2 is from another DLL project(both for windows and windows CE).

I don't know if I describe the problem clear, but I want to ask are there any way to make the source code that is both for `Windows` and `windows CE`  when in the source code some functions are from different DLLs ?

Any answers are appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first compiler error is somewhat self explanatory.  get "W" at the end of `GetProcAddressW` means that the method is the wide character API (as opposed to `GetProcAddressA`, which is the ASCII version).  Windows CE only exports the wide character versions of APIs.  That means that you have to pass in a wide-character string.  You used a TCHAR macro when you used `_T`, which makes the enclosed string a wide character literal, and the error goes away.

The same code should work fine on big Windows (for any recent version anyway), provided that you `#define UNICODE` (which is probably already on) and `#include "tchar.h"` which I think you since `_T` compiles.  You could explicitly call `GetProcAddressW` instead of just GetProcAddress (which should be #defined to the wide version if UNICODE is defined).

The source linker error you see isn't clear.  I'm guessing __imp_Function2 is a function pointer that you're trying to assign with the GetProcAddress call?  Basically the linker isn't finding it, but the root cause isn't clear with the info you've provided.

Comment: Hi ctacke, Thank you very much for the explaination. For the linking error, the CE console project is using the load-time dynamic linking. It includes a header file XXDriver.h of the XXDriver(windows project)(there is also a XXDriverCE project) and it uses the function directly from the XXDriver.h, e.g. Function2 in the linking error: LINK: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_Function2 
    referenced in function wmain    xxxx.obj    When I run the windows console project, it can use the function from the "XXDriver.h" correctly. But when I debugging the CE project on windows CE

Comment: device in visual studio2005, every function from the "XXDriver.h" occurred the above linking error. What do you think might be the reason cause these linking errors ?

Comment: Hi again, I have solved the linking problems. Except for only including the header file to the CE project, I still need to include the XXDriverCE.lib file from the XXDriverCE release folder. Now almost all above mentioned linking errors are solved. Thank you very much. I have too much to learn to developing DLL for windows and windows CE...